# Seeking software to perform basic editing of GPX files?

Tags: editing, gpx, software-recommendations

I'd like to do some basic editing to my GPX files which I record from my mobile. Features I'm looking for are:

1. open GPX file
2. display data of GPX overlayed on a map (google, bing, whatever)
3. select and delete points
4. select and move points
5. export back to GPX

What I've found so far:

- JOSM with the EditGpx plugin which doesn't do #4 (move points).
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpxeditor/ which doesn't do #4 (move points).
- GPS TracMaker which has a very poor points selection system.

The reason I want this is to offset part of the recorded path to fix possible GPS errors.

Is there a software which will allow me to do this?

Comment: OziExplorer can but it is not free. The free version of GPS TracMaker perhaps can also http://trackmaker.com/ but I am not sure about what is supported by the free version and what not. TrackMaker manual is at http://www.trackmaker.com/download/ref_guide_eng.pdf

Comment: @user30184 Thanks. GPS TracMaker seems to do everything, but its points selection is very very poor. On complex GPX where the points overlap (due to cycles on a specific track) it's impossible to properly select before moving.

Comment: Do you want to do this on your mobile (US: "cell phone") or on a laptop/desktop?

Comment: @Spacedman: Sorry for not mentioning it. Desktop windows or linux.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS can read GPX tracks, allow you to edit them over a base layer map (google, openstreetmap, stamen toner, etc) and save in any of a zillion formats.

Its Open Source, runs on Linux, Mac and Windows. There is an android port but I think its a bit beta and might be less functional.

[www.qgis.org](http://www.qgis.org)

I know you said "basic" GPX editor but these things grow up fast, and you'll grow with it.

I always check the OSGeo Live DVD for the best Open Source geo software, so maybe [GPS Prune](http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/gpsprune_overview.html) or something else will do it for you.

Comment: I wouldn't call QGIS as a GPX editor. Like GDAL http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html it can convert data from GPX into GIS layers and those GIS layers can be edited with QGIS. GPX editor as I would define it can edit the native structured XML data.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Garmin Basecamp for GPX editing. Possible free background maps can be all Openstreetmap derived Garmin maps. With routable maps, it is even possible to create new routes and upload them to the device. BaseCamp unfortunately does not run on Linux.

Editing capabilities are also offered by [Viking](http://sourceforge.net/projects/viking/), which can also have OSM tile background.

Alternatively, you can use [QlandkarteGT](http://www.qlandkarte.org/) for displaying GPX files on top of Garmin maps, Tile services like OSM or any available WMS service.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the exact same needs - after much research I stumbled across JGPSTrackEdit - it's written in Java and does everything you've requested & much more.  See: https://sourceforge.net/p/jgpstrackedit/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the requirements you have using JOSM.

```
open GPX file, right-click in layers window, convert to data layer.
select, delete and move points as required
open imagery layer (bing, Mapbox, etc, OpenStreetMap)
display data over the imagery 
Right-click the gpx data layer and export/convert to gpx
Right-click the gpx layer and change the track colour 
or customise the track drawing.
```